# How to give the JLabel Positioning from top to bottom and left to right

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel, imageicon

hi  i want to set Positioning of jlabel from top to bottom and left to right how can i do this
i tried setlocation(),setsize() and also other method but not able to achieve my desired output.

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TesstDemo1 extends JPanel {

    private static final int MAX = 20;
    private static final Font sans = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 16);
    private static final Border border =
            BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 16, 4, 16, Color.black);
    private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();

    public TesstDemo1() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\a0.png");
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(image, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        // titleLabel.setText("ImageSlider");
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 24));
        //   titleLabel.setBorder(border);
        this.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        imageLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        imageLabel.setOpaque(true);
        imageLabel.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        JPanel imageConstrain = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEFT));
        imageConstrain.add(imageLabel);
        imageLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        imageLabel.setBorder(border);
        this.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // this.add(imageConstrain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                TesstDemo1 go = new TesstDemo1();
                frame.add(go);
                frame.setTitle("ImageSlider");
                //  frame.setSize(400, 300);
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What `layout` you are using? It will be better if you show your code.

Comment: sorry i did not get your mean

Comment: U can use two grid layout side by side.

Comment: yes an i am using flow layout and also border

Comment: @anonymous...how can i use can u give me demo

Comment: What is the location you want the label to have?

Comment: The `GridBagLayout` would probably be the easiest to use. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information.

Comment: *"from top to bottom and left to right"*  Does that mean 'upper left'?  Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the layout then you apply the location. One example that should work is to set the layout to a Border layout then put the JPanel relative to center and if you don't want any other item on the frame it should cover the hole frame. Example code on frame class:

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.Center);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this if you have no LayoutManager. You'll have to set your layoutmanager to null. Setting your position of your JComponent with setBounds and call repaint. For more information take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: i do not want to use null layout

Comment: Then there is no other way if you want to have actual absolute position. You can work around if you try to add invisible components. But the BorderLayout can ignore your preferred Dimension.